# What components does "everybody" have?

Tags: game-design, components

When designing a board game to publish on the web, what components are safe to assume that most people will already have in their collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- chess
- checkers
- six-sided dice
- playing cards
- pen & paper
- coins
- simple play pieces (meeples or other incarnations)

Comment: Especially pen & paper are extremely versatile. I would add "a printer" to that, which gives you some features that pen & paper don't have.

Comment: I'd leave chess out...

Comment: I would also leave out checkers.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at what the Cheapass games come with and what they suggest you borrow from other games. Typically they assume players have:

- Dice
- Pawns / meeples / etc
- Counters such as coins / beads / etc
- Pen and paper
- A stack of paper money

Answer (score 5):

- pens/pencils
- paper
- dice
- playing cards
- coins

Answer (score 4):

I'll state the obvious ones:

- Chess
- Checkers
- Six-sided dice

Comment: Only six-sided dice for most people, though.  If you need D10s or something, then you limit your audience.

Comment: Dominoes are a strange addition to the list; I wouldn't think of them as universal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Richard and @Jadasc. I've incorporated it in my answer.

Comment: Dominoes are common but not *so* common you can expect people to have them. Yes, they might be easy to find (not so sure anyway), but only if you really *knew* in advance you needed them...

Answer (score 3):

- Nearly everybody has "play money" around in some form or another - from Monopoly, Life, or similar games
- Many households that lack a chess set will still have pawns from Sorry, Parcheesi, etc..